# why does it say Syntax,Error: invalid syntax at line 5

Tags: python, random, letter, chr, ord

```
from random import*
def saisie():
    ch1=""
    for i in range (1,9):
        ch1[i]=chr(randint(ord'A',ord'Z'))
        ch1=ch1+ch1[i]
    return ch1
```

i wanted to get a word randomly selected with capital and 8 letters

Comment: `ord'A'` should be `ord('A')`. This question is based on a typo. After you get the syntax error resolved, `ch1[i]` will fails as soon as `i > 0` since that index will be out of bounds.

Comment: The easiest way to get what you want is with the 1-liner `''.join(choices(string.ascii_uppercase,k=8))` (after you import `string`).

Answer (score 1):

ord is a function, so you should change your code like this

```
from random import*
def saisie():
    ch1=""
    for i in range (1,9):
        ch1[i]=chr(randint(ord('A'),ord('Z')))
        ch1=ch1+ch1[i]
    return ch1
```

**UPD**
as @John Coleman said there is still bugs in code

1. index will be out of bounds
2. string are immutable so you can't assign by index

here is the working example

```
from random import*
def saisie():
    ch1=""
    for i in range (8):
        ch1 += chr(randint(ord('A'),ord('Z')))
    return ch1
```

Comment: The code still has a bug.

Comment: Thanks)
I just made changes to get rid of syntax error
But I'll update with working example